# Adding up the total of a car model from all years

Tags: python, pandas

So one of my task is to take all the cars that were made after certain year and add them all up together. My problem is from the car data, I am able to filter out the correct car year and origin, but when I try to use the count() function it gives me the incorrect numbers.

```
car_count = cars.loc[(cars['OG'] == 'Japan') & (cars['Year'] > 
1999)].count() 

car_count

OG    24190
Year     24190
Model     24190
Count    24190
```

If I do not include count() then my output looks something like this

```
OG    | Year | Maker | Count
Japan | 1997 | Honda | 992
Japan | 1997 | Toyota| 278
US    | 1997 | Ford  | 453
Japan | 1998 | Honda | 2667
Japan | 1998 | Toyota| 213
```

I have been trying to make my output look like this

```
Maker
Honda | 3659
Toyota| 491
```

Comment: See the above link for some suggestions about how to solve your problem.